# What does the command `:syntax reset` do?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

from  the help: `:h syntax-reset`

> If you have changed the colors and messed them up, use this command to
>   get the defaults back: >
>
> :syntax reset
>
> It is a bit of a wrong name, since it does not reset any syntax items,
>   it only affects the highlighting.
>
> This doesn't change the colors for the 'highlight' option.

so this tells us: *it does not reset any syntax items* and it doesnt
 *change the `highlight` option*

what does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It resets the colors for

- Comment
- Constant
- Special
- Identifier
- Statement
- PreProc
- Type
- Underline
- Ignore

according to the selected background (dark or light).

Links that point to these colors (`String`, `Number`, etc.) are also reset.

See https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim